# tf.one_hot returning array filled with 0's

Tags: tensor, one-hot-encoding

I am new to deep learning, I am trying to do one hot encoding of this tensor

```
E = tf.constant(np.random.randint(1,100,size = 10))
E
```

Output

> <tf.Tensor: shape=(10,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([48, 85, 75, 25, 28, 49,  3, 51, 47, 96])>

After using tf.one_hot() the returned array is

```
tf.one_hot(E,depth=10)
```

Output

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(10, 10), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
```

In returned tensor most one hot encoded values are
[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]

According to me in one hot encoding there should be unique vector for each value but here there is same vector for many values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your random integers are in the range 1-100, you'll need to keep **depth=100** in the one_hot function.

Conversely, you can reduce the range of random integers to 1-10.

The idea is that if your number ranges between 1-100, it needs as many bits to represent the one-hot encoding, which you haven't provided by restricting the depth to 10.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
E = tf.constant(np.random.randint(1,10,size = 10))
tf.one_hot(E,depth=10)
```

**Output:**

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(10, 10), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
   [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
```